# Elementary question on the intersection of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was curious about set intersections.
I know that 
$\{x\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]\;\forall x\in{R}$.

Then, what would be the followings?
$(i) \lim_{n\to\infty}[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})\\
(ii) \lim_{n\to\infty}(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})\\
(iii) \lim_{n\to\infty}[x,x+\frac{1}{n}]\\
(iv) \lim_{n\to\infty}[x,x+\frac{1}{n})\\
(v) \lim_{n\to\infty}(x,x+\frac{1}{n}]\\
(vi) \lim_{n\to\infty}(x,x+\frac{1}{n})$

Are there any criteria to handle these kind of questions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For each of these, the intervals are contained in the respective $\left[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right]$. Thus the intersection is a subset of $\{x\}$. There isn't much choice, and finding which applies in each case isn't difficult.

Comment: The notation $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ for an intersection is highly unusual. More standard is $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I see your point. Your suggestion seems to be a better way. I used it because the seq. of sets are descending.

Answer (score 1):

The question was sorted out in comments: the intersection is either $\{x\}$ or empty, depending on whether $x$ is in the given intervals.

I'll remark that the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$ has legitimate use, just as $\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n$ and  $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$. In all three cases, one introduces *characteristic functions* 
$$
\chi_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1,\quad x\in A_n \\ 0, \quad x\notin A_n\end{cases}
$$
and considers the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_n(x)$. If the limit exists for every $x$, then the set of all $x$  where the limit is equal to $1$ is defined to be $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$.

One has the familiar facts like: $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ exists if and only if $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$.

For nested sequences, the limit becomes intersection (if they are decreasing) or union (if they are increasing).

Exercise: $\lim_{n\to\infty} [n,2n]= \varnothing$.